# How to save vCards-js automatically on Iphone & Android contacts

Tags: javascript, ios

i am trying to save a vcard on users phone (IOS & ANDROID). I am using this code

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  // Contact Information
  var contact = {
    ...
  };
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n"
    + "N:" + contact.name + ";;;\n"
    + "FN:" + contact.name + "\n"
    + "TEL;CELL:" + contact.phone + "\n"
    + "TEL;CELL:" + contact.mobile + "\n"
    + "EMAIL;HOME:" + contact.email + "\n"
    + "ADR;HOME:" + contact.address + "\n"
    + "ORG;WORK:" + contact.organization + "\n"
    + "TITLE:" + contact.title + "\n"
    + "URL:" + contact.url + "\n"
    + "NOTE:" + contact.notes + "\n"
    + "END:VCARD";  
  
  // var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
  newLink.textContent = contact.name;
  newLink.href = url;
  
  newLink.click();

  // window.close();
});
```

And it works, but this code on android phone first download a vcard and later users need to make a click on download to make import. What i want is when user go to this page , my contact save automatically on android without downloading any File. (On IOS is not a problem couse when user go to this web they redirect automatically to import contact)

`NOTE:` I have sow before an example with qr code. When i scan qr code they redirect me to import contact and what i need to do is only to click `save` on my phone

I want same thing as this https://www.qr-code-generator.com when click on vCard tab. But when page reload, not to scan qr code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method of **web share API**, according to your code you can add the **navigator.share()** with in condition  like if checks if this API support by the browser then it will auto download else download link.

Like this below updated code :-

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  // Contact Information
  var contact = {
    ...
  };
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\n"
    + "N:" + contact.name + ";;;\n"
    + "FN:" + contact.name + "\n"
    + "TEL;CELL:" + contact.phone + "\n"
    + "TEL;CELL:" + contact.mobile + "\n"
    + "EMAIL;HOME:" + contact.email + "\n"
    + "ADR;HOME:" + contact.address + "\n"
    + "ORG;WORK:" + contact.organization + "\n"
    + "TITLE:" + contact.title + "\n"
    + "URL:" + contact.url + "\n"
    + "NOTE:" + contact.notes + "\n"
    + "END:VCARD";  
  
  // var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
  if (navigator.share) {
  
    navigator.share({
    
      title: 'New Contacts',
      text: 'Save contacts',
      files: [new File([blob], 'newcontact.vcf', { type: 'text/vcard' })],
    }).then(() => { });

  } else {
      const newLink = document.createElement('a');
      newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
      newLink.textContent = contact.name;
      newLink.href = url;

      newLink.click();

      // window.close();
  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution is to save a vCard contact automatically on an Android device without requiring the user to download and import the file, you can use the `navigator.contacts` API provided by the device's web browser (e.g., Chrome). Example:

```js
var contact = {
  displayName: "Melon Dusk",
  phoneNumbers: [
    {
      type: "mobile",
      value: "123-456-7890",
      pref: true
    }
  ],
  emails: [
    {
      type: "home",
      value: "melon.dusk@xcorp.com"
    }
  ],
  addresses: [
    {
      type: "home",
      formatted: "123 Main St\nAnytown, USA 12345"
    }
  ],
  organizations: [
    {
      type: "work",
      name: "XCorp Inc.",
      title: "Undefined"
    }
  ],
  urls: [
    {
      type: "home",
      value: "https://www.xcorp.69"
    }
  ],
  note: "Am I a note?"
};

navigator.contacts.save(contact, function () {
  console.log("Contact saved successfully");
}, function (error) {
  console.error("Error saving contact: " + error);
});
```